# time function in Python for add an interval to a datetime object

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I want to do some queries on PostgreSQL database.

I wonder what package or built-in function  can do these.

```
origin_time = 2014-02-21 00:00:00
origin_time + '1 week' #  2014-02-28 00:00:00
origin_time + '3 hours' # 2014-02-21 00:06:00
```

Comment: Take a look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to do calculations in PostgreSQL or Python? Your example appears more similar to Python than PostgreSQL, but your question says you're working in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the string to `datetime.datetime` object. (DB API module do this for you.) And use `datetime.timedelta` to time addition.

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> origin_time = '2014-02-21 00:00:00'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(origin_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> d + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)  # + 1 week
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 28, 0, 0)
>>> d + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)  # + 3 hours
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 21, 3, 0)
```

Use [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to get back string:

```
>>> (d + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2014-02-21 03:00:00'

>>> '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d + datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
'2014-02-21 03:00:00'
```

Comment: Don't the DB client libraries (such as psycopg2) already handle converting to a `datetime` object?